# PyQt5 Python: How to go through Individual Row of Data from MySQL Query Result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, mysql-python, qcombobox

I am trying to add item in a QComboBox in PyQt5 using Python. I am having problems in adding data from the SQL Query per row.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
            query = "SELECT buyerID, lastName, firstName, middleName FROM buyer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            item = list()
            for a, b, c, d in data:
                row = "{} | {}, {} {}".format(a, b, c, d)
                item.append(row)
            self.customerID.addItem(str(item))
```

This results to only a single item added into the Combo Box:

```
100000 | lastName, firstName middleName, 100000 | lastName, firstName middleName, 100000 | lastName, firstName middleName...etc.
```

What I want to happen in the ComboBox is like this (Add a total of 5 items in the Combo Box)

```
100001 | lastName, firstName middleName
100002 | lastName, firstName middleName
100003 | lastName, firstName middleName
100004 | lastName, firstName middleName
100005 | lastName, firstName middleName
```

Edit:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = "SELECT buyerID, lastName, firstName, middleName FROM buyer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
item = list()
for a, b, c, d in data:
    row = "{} | {}, {} {}".format(a, b, c, d)
    item.append(row)
    self.customerID.addItem(str(item))  <------- I just moved this line of code into the FOR loop statement to add the item per loop.
```

Same Problem:

The appended Item added is still all the rows of data grouped into one.

Comment: Just use [`addItems(item)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItems) (note the final "s").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question and tinkering on myself, I stumbled upon the answer to my question as I realized that I had to change the FOR LOOP statement to enumerate over the length of the data from MySQL Query Result and  **.addItem** to the ComboBox before it goes on to the next tuple from the results from **data** (SQL Query Result).

```
for a in enumerate(data):                 <--- changed the for loop statement to "enumerate" how many data inside the MySQL Query Result
     j, k = a                             <--- split (index, tuple) in a
     l, m, n, o = k                       <--- separate tuple into strings
     string = "{} | {}, {} {}".format(l, m, n, o)
     self.customerID.addItem(str(string)) <------- I just moved this line of code into the FOR loop statement to add the item before moving on to the next row in SQL results.
```